# How to populate db from array resource?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In /values/arrays.xml, I have an array that contains values that I would like to insert into an sqlite db.

In onCreate, I'm trying to get that array and run a for loop until i = length of the array and then using db.execSQL("INSERT INTO... or possibly initialValues.put(...

However, I can't seem to getResources() in onCreate, so I'm not even sure if this will work. Does anybody know how best to do this?

Answer (score 0):

this seems to have what your after:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>

Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

then just loop through it as normal

Comment: I can't seem to get around "The method getResources() is undefined" Any ideas?

Comment: hmm can you show the relevant code? is it just in your Apps main activity onCreate? getResources is a method of the context. You should be able to use either this.getResources() from the activity or if its in another class then pass the context along and try context.getResources(). Hope that helps?

Comment: It's in my DbAdapter class, here is the file I'm working off of... http://code.google.com/p/android-helloworld-samples/source/browse/trunk/Notepadv3/src/com/android/demo/notepad3/NotesDbAdapter.java?r=28

Comment: ahh yep, so that class doesn't have a getResources method you need to call it via the Activity's context so try context.getResources() remember you pass the context from your Activity to the DatabaseHelper class. I'm no expert though but i think that's what you need :)

Comment: thinking about that though, why are you trying to access the Array resource in your Db adapter, is it more elegant to access it in the onCreate of your Activity? Then loop through results and pass each item to a db adapter insert method

Comment: context cannot be resolved. And right now, I have about 50 insert statements in the onCreate of my DbAdapter, just looking to clean it up and put those initial values in an array.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this straight, you're trying to add these initial values from the dbAdapter. I see no reason why you shouldn't move this procedure to the main class. I like to keep dbAdapter's methods strictly related to creation/read/write of the database, and then I populate the list in the main Activity. You will have direct access to the resources as well.

As a performance enhancer, you should try to make insert all records in one statement such as

```
db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO tableName(column1, column2) VALUES (valA1, valA2), (valB1, valB2) ....
```

You can make this query-String by simple String operations while iterating over the array. Good luck! :-)

Comment: If I put it in the main class, it's going to get hit every time I run the app. These are initial values that should be populated when the database is created, that's why they are on onCreate of the db. The user is free to delete these values, so I don't want to keep putting them in. Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you implement it. However, I'm not completely sure about the lifecycle of a SQLite-database so it might be a good idea to keep it where you originally thought of. I saw that you were unable to get the context, this is something that we can fix. Given that you use the code in the link you provided, all you have to do is add `private Context context;` to dbAdapter and set this in the constructor as this: `this.context = context;` Please let me know if you're having problems with this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing. I assume you know about making the database helper class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` so I won't go into that. This is used to create or update the database when the app is installed. When this class is called you pass it the `Context`. Make another class level variable to hold the context and then initialize it in the constructor. Then you use the context to `getResources()` from which you can get the array to populate your database.

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context fContext;

    // constructor
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        fContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + FIRST_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + SECOND_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + THIRD_COLUMN + " INTEGER,"
                + FOURTH_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL"
                + ");");

        // Initialize the db with values from my_array.xml
        final int DEFAULT_THIRD_COLUMN = 1;
        final String DEFAULT_FOURTH_COLUMN = "";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        Resources res = fContext.getResources();
        String[] myArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_array);
        for (String item : myArray){
            values.put(SECOND_COLUMN, item);
            values.put(THIRD_COLUMN, DEFAULT_THIRD_COLUMN);
            values.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, DEFAULT_FOURTH_COLUMN);
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

See [this link](http://martin.cubeactive.com/android-filling-a-table-from-resource-file-with-string-array-sqlite/) for more help: